# SQL Server 2008 - Migrating AuditLog table to each table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, data-migration

I'm trying to migrate data from an AuditLog table, which is referenced by many tables, onto the tables themselves.  I have a table, TablesWithAuditLogs, that contains the physical table names of each table that needs migration. I'm having a hard time determining if this is even possible in SQL alone.

Let's say I have these five tables, 3 of which require migration from the AuditLog.CreatedOn column to the self.CreatedOn column (It's actually more like 80 tables):

```
AuditLog
--------
ID:     CreatedOn:
1       2015-01-02
2       2015-03-04
3       2015-05-06
4       2014-02-01
5       2010-01-01
6       2011-03-04

TablesWithAuditLogs
-------------------
ID:     TableName:
41      'Contacts'
42      'Addresses'
43      'Items'

Contacts
--------
ID:     AuditLogId:   CreatedOn:
10      1             null
11      3             null

Addresses
---------
ID:     AuditLogId:   CreatedOn:
20      4             null
21      5             null

Items
-----
ID:     AuditLogId:   CreatedOn:
30      2             null
31      6             null
```

The desired result from the SQL statement would be:

```
Contacts
--------
ID:     AuditLogId:   CreatedOn:
10      1             2015-01-02
11      3             2015-05-06

Addresses
---------
ID:     AuditLogId:   CreatedOn:
20      4             2014-02-01
21      5             2010-01-01

Items
-----
ID:     AuditLogId:   CreatedOn:
30      2             2015-03-04
31      6             2011-03-04
```

Then I could delete the AuditLogId column from each of the 80 tables and also drop the AuditLog table entirely.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What would be the expected result?

Comment: Edit your answer and post the expected result please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could to this using a `CURSOR` and `Dynamic SQL`:

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(100)

DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY FOR
    SELECT TableName FROM TablesWithAuditLogs

OPEN cur
FETCH FROM cur INTO @tableName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    SELECT @sql ='
    UPDATE t
        SET t.CreatedOn = a.CreatedOn
    FROM [' + @tableName + '] t
    INNER JOIN AuditLog a
        ON a.ID = t.AuditLogID'

    EXEC(@sql)

    FETCH FROM cur INTO @tableName
END

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
```

**RESULT**

```
Contacts
----------------------------------
ID          AuditLogID  CreatedOn
----------- ----------- ----------
10          1           2015-01-02
11          3           2015-05-06

Addresses
----------------------------------
ID          AuditLogID  CreatedOn
----------- ----------- ----------
20          4           2014-02-01
21          5           2010-01-01

Items
----------------------------------
ID          AuditLogID  CreatedOn
----------- ----------- ----------
30          2           2015-03-04
31          6           2011-03-04
```

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e3ed9/1/0)

Comment: Thank you so much!  I ran it and everything is awesome.